# Set TYPO3 extbase storagePageIds / storagePid to current

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am using the TYPO3 extension feupload, which relies on extbase. This is my first contact with extbase.
But the question is about extbase in general.

I expect TYPO3 to include the usual "IN (current-page)" pid check by default in queries, unless told otherwise - but in extbase that seems to be different. Or at least in my case, it's not working.

In the extension, there is a constants / setup setting, where the storagePid can be set. This works.
But we don't want to adapt that parameter manually for each page.

```
persistence {
       # cat=feupload/persistence; type=integer; label=Storage PID of records
       storagePid =
}
```

So how do I make extbase get the PID of the current page automatically as expected?

(Sub-question: I've tried to set plugin.tx_pluginname.persistence.storagePid.data = {page:uid} in setup, but that wouldn't work. What would the TS have to look like to work?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, what you did *should* work, but you have to write it like this:

```
plugin.tx_pluginname.persistence.storagePid.data = page:uid
```

(the {} is only necessary when you insert a data field in an ordinary wrap)

As others pointed out, you have to make sure you include the extension's configuration in your template.

If the above fails, you can programatically set the storagePid in your controller's initializeAction, like so:

```php
$querySettings = $this->myRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
$querySettings->setStoragePageIds(array($GLOBALS["TSFE"]->id));
$this->myRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested on TYPO3 ver. 4.7.x and [getText](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/getText) function did the trick:

```
plugin.tx_test {
  persistence {
    storagePid.data = field:uid
  }
}
```

Put this in the `TS Setup` of the main page, and overwrite on subpage(s) if required.

Comment: I've tried it in TYPO3 4.5 with EXT:feupload, where it's not working. Probably hard to reproduce though. Do you know if extbase should be including the "current pid" condition in the query by default?

Comment: Have you included the typoscript configuration in your template? And no, Extbase does not include the current pid by default. You have to set the storagePid or turn it of in your own queries.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Typo3 6.1.8

```
plugin.tx_test {
  persistence {
    storagePid.override.cObject = TEXT
    storagePid.override.cObject.field = uid
  }
}
```

Comment: With this code you can set your storageID to the current page. Add the code to your extension config file.