# How to get an array of fe_groups in TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions

I'm pretty new to TYPO3 and many things are confusing at the moment, especially how the data modeling and data fetching actually works if you're relying on ExtBase.

Thing I want to achive is to get an array of records from the `fe_groups` table and pass it into my Fluid view and render those items in `f:form.select` input field.

So far, I've tried nothing since I have no idea from where and how to start it.

Other thing I've did successfully is to pass a hard coded array of object items into my view, and rendered them successfully, like this:

```
<f:form.select
    class="form-control"
    property="taskTypes"
    options="{taskTypes}"
    optionValueField="name"
    optionLabelField="value"
    id="taskTypes" />
```

This is the method in my Controller which fills the `taskTypes` array:

```
private function getTaskTypes() {
    $task_type_names = [
        ' - Task Types - ',
        'New client',
        'Maintenance',
    ];
    $task_types = [];

    foreach($task_type_names as $i => $task_type_name) {
        $task_type = new \stdClass();
        $task_type->key = $i;
        $task_type->value = $task_type_name;

        $task_types[] = $task_type;
    }

    return $task_types;
}
```

And then a simple view assignment in controller's action:

```
$this->view->assign('taskTypes', $this->getTaskTypes());
```

And this works like a charm!

But I'm clueless how to do something similar with dynamic content fetched from the database tables.

So, basically, I just need a way to pass items from `fe_groups` table to my view and render them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to inject the Repository for FrontenduserGroups from Extbase

```
 /**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserGroupRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $feUserGroupRepository;
```

in your method you can then use this Repository to get the data from the database

```
$feUserGroup = $this->feUserGroupRepository->findAll();
$userByUid = $this->feUserGroupRepository->findByUid(12);
```

The repository also provides more `->findBy*` methods.
Here is a cheatsheet that might help you http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-query-methods/

Note:

- the `@inject` in the doc comment is actually parsed by Extbase and loads the class that is refered in `@var`
- the `storagePid` needs to be set to the UID of the folder that contains the usergroups in the backend

Comment: Could I do the injection with a method instead of using `@inject`? I had problems with that so I try to avoid it...

Comment: You can inject the class by writing a methos injectFrontendUserGroupRepository() and provide the namespace for FrontendUserGroupRepository as parameter.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. It injects the repository, but findAll doesn't return anything, but I have data in that table.

Comment: That sounds like the "storagePid" is not set. the storagePid needs to be set to the ID of the folder that contains your usergroups in backend.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244616/set-typo3-extbase-storagepageids-storagepid-to-current

Comment: I've set it up, but still does not work... I've set it like `storagePid = 28` where my groups are defined.